# Regex find a string inside a string that doesn't being with a string

Tags: regex, string

In short, i'm trying to determine if a String has already been escaped. So i need to find all occurrences of ' that don't have \ in front.

```
Input: "Hello world" Output: false
Input: "Hello ' world" Output: true
Input: "Hello \' wor'ld" Oputput: true
Input: "Hello \' wor\'ld" Output: false
```

Not sure how to begin working on this

Comment: are you doign this in a programm or with a simple regex utility (like sed)? in code, you could also just search for the indices of ' characters, and look at the char at this index - 1.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Stack Overflow. Whilst I can appreciate that you don't know how to start solving the problem, but Stack Overflow works best when you have a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that you ask for help on.

Comment: What language / tools are you looking to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following regex which use a [*negative look behind*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for miss matching the backslash :

```
.*(?<!\\)'.*
```

See demo https://regex101.com/r/vM3tG6/1